# How to pass parameter from cron command to codeigniter function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cron-task

I am working with code-igniter and running a function from cron job.

```
class event extends CI_Controller {
  public function newEvent()
    {
         //some process here using the parameter
    }

}
```

cron command:

```
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/project/index.php 'event/newEvent/parameter'
```

I want to pass the parameter like written in cron command and do some process with that parameter in newEvent function.

What extra code I should write in my function to receive the parameter from cron command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this and it's working for me.

```
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://domain.com/index.php/event/newEvent/parameter
```

Comment: That's another great way to do it.  Did it worked out of the box or did you had to add a parameter to your method?

Comment: I have added a parameter in my method.

Comment: It does work but not recommended over cli method provided by codeigniter. Running through curl or wget makes your function publicly visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a parameter to your function.

```
class event extends CI_Controller {

    public function newEvent($parameter)
    {
        //some process here using the parameter
        echo $parameter;
    }

}
```

The default routing engine will proceed your parameter and pass it to your function.  If that parameter is optional, feel free to initialize it to something by default.

```
    public function newEvent($parameter = 'default')
    {
        //some process here using the parameter
        echo $parameter;
    }
```

Edit: After reading's @dm03514 answer, it seems that the [documentation recommends](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) to call your application with spaces instead of slashes.

The cron command should be

```
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/project/index.php event newEvent parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

CI [explains](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) how to execute command from the command line in their documentation

`php index.php event newEvent parameter`

Comment: You were quicker than me on that one! :)